# Knitr Spin and Rmarkdown Fig.cap (figure caption). Producing double numbering pdf document

Tags: pdf, ms-word, knitr, figure

I am referring to this [Suppress automatic figure numbering in pdf output with r markdown/knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842133/suppress-automatic-figure-numbering-in-pdf-output-with-r-markdown-knitr/41659291#41659291)
which I don't think was answered fully.

Essentially, I am using knitr::spin and rmarkdown to produce word, pdf and html documents.

For word, there appears to be no numbering when one puts in 
+fig.1, fig.cap = "Figure name"
You only get an output Figure name in the caption.
To solve that, I used captioner class.
figs = captioner("Figure")
That works fine for word

But I am not faced with rewriting the script for pdf document as the caption turns up as figure 1: figure 1: The name

I am using knitr::spin to actually generate the RMD document for forward outputs in word and pdf.

I am not sure I can use hooks in knitr::spin, as I have tried it as advertised but can't get it to work.

### I also tried

header-includes: \usepackage{caption} \usepackage{float}

\captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

as suggested somehere to surpress the prefix for pdf but I get errors from pandoc. It uses pdf2latex.

I am not sure how one would query the output format in knitr::spin to actually produce different actions for different formats which could be a solution although cumbersome.

Thank you so much for your help from a novice.

Comment: I have explained why it is not a duplicate in the original question that you have referred to. In fact, the original question does not have a satisfactory answer. It can be reopened with the variation of the parameters that I describe in the current question or it can be answered here.

Comment: the working environment is different. I don't use any latex and I am using knitr:spin directly. I asked the similar question in the one you said could be the answer and you advised me to open a new question.

Comment: Anyone provide an answer yet? This still seems to be an open issue. Thanks.