# How to suppress automatic figure numbering in Rmarkdown / pandoc

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I have the following Rmarkdown (.Rmd) document where I call existing .png images and create a .pdf with captions. By default, pandoc? is automatically adding "Figure #." before the caption for each picture. I can see how this would be the normal thing to do, but in my case I would like to define this. I have found variations on this topic but don't seem to find a solution. Below is an example of how my .Rmd file looks:

````
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "ME"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

![Caption for figure 1](figures/plot1.png)


\newpage

![Caption for figure 2](figures/plot2.png)
````

Comment: Do you want to remove or edit the numbering?

Comment: I would like to remove the numbering completely.

Comment: So you just want " Figure: Caption for figure 1" or absolutely no caption?

Comment: Well, to be specific, I would use "Figure S1. Caption for figure 1". But, I would be happy with removing the automatic insertion of "Figure" completely if that's easier.

Comment: so add `fig_caption: FALSE` to your YAML header, under `pdf_document:`

Comment: would this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842133/suppress-automatic-figure-numbering-in-pdf-output-with-r-markdown-knitr

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the caption-package

Create a .tex-file that you specify the following in, this below remove the entire label and you are free to hardcode the labels.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
```

Then your .rmd should look like this:

````
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "ME"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: YourName.tex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

![Caption for figure 1](figures/plot1.png)

\newpage

![Caption for figure 2](figures/plot2.png)
````

***Simplified:*** As suggested in the comments, we can achieve this within our `.Rmd` file, as shown below.

````
---
title: "TITLE"
author: "ME"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
- \captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

![Caption for figure 1](figures/plot1.png)

\newpage

![Caption for figure 2](figures/plot2.png)
````

Comment: Just found out that the lines of YourName.tex can be put directly in the starting lines:

`header-includes:
  \usepackage{caption}
  \captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}`

Comment: @Marcinthebox Nice! In most of my own reports I do quite a bit of latex non-default stuff but for those times were you just use the odd package that's much simpler

Comment: thanks a lot @Marcinthebox, I had looked for this for quite long

Comment: To suppress the autolabeling for tables, add another line in the YAML swapping out "table" for "figure": - \captionsetup[table]{labelformat=empty}