# Disable automatic figure numbers? (html to pdf with pandoc)

Tags: html, pdf, pandoc

**Is it possible tell pandoc to disable automatic figure numbering when converting from html to pdf?**

Here's some simple html:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <figure id="figure_site_map" >
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/77/Google_Images_2015_logo.svg/300px-Google_Images_2015_logo.svg.png" style="max-height:6in; max-width:7in;" />
   <figcaption>
    Figure 9.
    A picture.
   </figcaption>
  </figure>
 </body>
</html>
```

Simple pandoc command:

```
$ pandoc test.html -o test.pdf
```

I expect the figure caption in the pdf to look like this:

> Figure 9. A picture.

But, pandoc is automatically numbering the figure, starting at 1, producing a caption like this:

> Figure 1: Figure 9. A picture.

---

Some stuff that didn't work:

- I know that the `native_numbering` extension exists, but it's not intended for html, and I get an error if I try to disable it.

  > The extension native_numbering is not supported for html
- I found this related thread, but that solution (adding custom `header-includes`) didn't work either.

  [How to suppress automatic figure numbering in Rmarkdown / pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852069/how-to-suppress-automatic-figure-numbering-in-rmarkdown-pandoc)
- Using `--from markdown` creates the correct figure caption, but the image isn't included.

Comment: putting some LaTeX in the `header-includes` sounds like the right approach... try `-t latex` to see what pandoc feeds to pdflatex to generate the PDF (see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf).